# Usar SELECT en consulta con condicional IN mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Lo que tengo es un Procedimiento Almacenado

```
Begin

declare _otrospadrones varchar(30);

SET _otrospadrones=(SELECT group_concat(DISTINCT a.id SEPARATOR ' , ') as ids from asociados WHERE npa=1)


SELECT s.nrostand as N°stand,
a.id as idAsociado,
p.idrecaudo as idRecaudo,

FROM pagos p
INNER JOIN stands s on s.id=p.id_stand
INNER JOIN asociados a ON a.id=s.idasociado
INNER JOIN recaudos r ON r.id=p.idrecaudo
INNER JOIN pasadizos pz on pz.nropasadizo=s.pasadizo
WHERE a.id in (_otrospadrones) AND p.estado=0
```

El primer `select _otrospadrones` me retorna una cadena `"1,15"` y esta cadena la intento usar para condicionar mediante `IN` en el Segundo select, pero la consulta solo me devuelve filas de `a.id = 1`, supongo que se trunca, por que dentro de los valores de in se encuentran con un string `("1,15")`.

> ¿Cómo puede hacer que me tome adecuadamente el valor de _otrospadrones en la seguda consulta?

esta pista puede servir.
**Warning: #1292 Equivocado truncado DOUBLE valor: '1,15'**

Comment: no se particularmente tu error, pero no entiendo porque no escribis el select directamente dentro del in.. sabias que podias hacer eso???

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, intense eso. y sigue truncándose la consulta.

Comment: Como menciono @gbianchi puedes hacer directamente el select, no creo que necesites el separator, estas intentado hacer coincidir tu output con uno de los usos de in puedes ver estos otros links que tienen info > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135376/mysql-select-where-field-in-subquery-extremely-slow-why
> > https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/

Comment: Intenta así: `WHERE a.id in (SELECT DISTINCT a.id from asociados WHERE npa=1) AND p.estado=0`, aunque para fines de desempeño no es lo mas recomendable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encontré la solución en base  prueba y error, siguiendo  los errores, luego regrese al post.

1. en mi sub consulta, trato de hacer coincidir mi variable _otrospadrones, caso que me toma con si fuera un string "1,5" (retorno de select).
2. IN puede recibir una columna de una tabla (esto es lo que no COMPRENDIA).
3. existe dos opciones:
   a. si la sub consulta para IN se usara varias veces en el mismo procedimiento, se puede crear una tabla temporal.
   b. si es que la subconsulta para IN solo se usa una sola vez, como indico Lucero , se hace la sub consulta directamente.

pego mi código que funciona:

```
Begin

SELECT s.nrostand as N°stand,
a.id as idAsociado,
p.idrecaudo as idRecaudo,

FROM pagos p
INNER JOIN stands s on s.id=p.id_stand
INNER JOIN asociados a ON a.id=s.idasociado
INNER JOIN recaudos r ON r.id=p.idrecaudo
INNER JOIN pasadizos pz on pz.nropasadizo=s.pasadizo
WHERE stands.idasociado IN (SELECT a.id as ids from asociados WHERE npa=1) AND p.estado=0
```

Solucionado , gracias,